# Service communication using Events or RxJS in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

There are 2 service A and B. I want to trigger a event/subject when a specific method is called in A and notify B.

Note: I can not directly access A from B and B from A due to some restriction.

I have created a service C which both A and B can access, and have defined a BehaviorSubject in C.

If A triggers, B can subscriber using BehaviorSubject in C. (that was my thought)

The issue is BehaviorSubject works when it is inside a lifecycle hook preferably ngOnInit() of a component.

So the above way does not work. Any suggestions or way around.

This is the Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mjqzwc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can inject service A and B to service C?

Comment: No.. I can have C injected in A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample, the thing that i assume you are doing is that you don't inject all of your services.

In the example below the thing that will happen is whenever you click the button `click` you will send a notifcation that will go like so `Service B => Service C => Service B && Service A`

The important thing is that I'm injecting both `Service A` and `Service B` in my app.component, otherwise if i don't inject `Service A` in my component the service will be three shaken, which will lead to a behaviour when the service is not being initialized which means that no `subscribtion` will be made.

```js
// A service
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CService } from "./c.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AService {
  constructor(private cService: CService) {
    this.cService.notifications$.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x, "Notification in A service");
    });
  }
}

// B service
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CService } from "./c.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class BService {
  constructor(private cService: CService) {
    this.cService.store$.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x, "notification In B service");
    });
  }

  notify(message) {
    console.log(message);
    this.cService.pushNotificationToSubscribers(message);
  }
}

// C service
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class CService {
  store$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  notifications$ = this.store$;

  pushNotificationToSubscribers = notification => {
    this.store$.next(notification);
  };
}

// App componet e.g. where the services are used

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AService } from "./services/a.service";
import { BService } from "./services/b.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: "<button (click)="notify()">Click me</button>",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private bService: BService, private aService: AService) {}

  notify() {
    this.bService.notify("New notification");
  }
}
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/communication-between-services?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (Open your console to see the results)